# WhatsApp media is not showing up from WhatsApp account when migrated from old phone

Tags: sync, whatsapp-messenger, gallery, media-files

I bought a new phone, so I took a backup from the old phone's WhatsApp account and installed in the new phone. Now at the time of installation I chose the "Restore" option from the backup so it can restore the messages and media.

Now I was using an SD card as the storage device in my old phone for WhatsApp. So all the images are on the SD card, and I can view them in *Gallery*. But when I am trying to go to any contact's "Media" option I am not able to see any images/videos which I was able to view from old phone.

So how do I see the media from a contact's home in WhatsApp which are in gallery?

Comment: @beeshyams you are right Whatsapp is installed in internal storage. I didn't get the second part of your solution. I went to the "system apps" but not able to find **media storage**

Comment: No. I can't be able to find it. If it is of any help... I am using Redmi Note 4 (Marshmallow) and MIUI-8 interface.

Comment: I used a different technique. A post from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/My-WhatsApp-photos-on-my-SD-card-are-not-showing-in-the-Photos-app-on-my-Lumia-phone-What-should-I-do/answer/Nishi-Mahto). Will update the answer later.

Comment: Good. Then please delete comments comments as clean up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took help from [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/My-WhatsApp-photos-on-my-SD-card-are-not-showing-in-the-Photos-app-on-my-Lumia-phone-What-should-I-do/answer/Nishi-Mahto), and I figured out that WhatsApp is installed in internal memory. That's why it isn't able pick up the pictures/media from the SD card. Here is what I did.

1. I renamed the WhatsApp folder in the internal memory. From `Whatsapp` to `Whatsapp_backup`.
2. Rebooted the phone.
3. Downloaded an image from a chat. This forced to create another `Whatsapp` folder to be created in internal memory.
4. Then moved all the content from `SD Card/Whatsapp/Media` to Internal `Whatsapp/Media` folder.
5. Then I closed WhatsApp and started again. This made WhatsApp to refresh the memory index and pick the media file according to chats.

Comment: Is the folder name actually "Whatsapp" (not "WhatsApp")?

Comment: @PeterMortensen We can well believe that a human can identify wrong capitalization by himself.